# Typescript passing a type as a parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

using Directus SDK.
Im trying to do a function that does this, I just want to change the type(CollectionsNameChanges) everytime the function is called

```
const directus = new Directus<CollectionsNameChanges>('https://mysamelink/');
```

For this I created this function

**connection.ts**

```
//here I want to get a new Type, that's why I am passing title as a parameter

export function DirectusConnection(title: any) {
  return new Directus<typeof title>('https://mysamelink/');
}
```

**myList.ts**

```
interface MyTypes {
  id: number;
}

export async function myFunction(){
  type CollectionsNameChanges= {
    //collection name
    nameofCollection: MyTypes;
  };

//here I am calling my function with the type
  const directus = DirectusConnection(<CollectionsNameChanges>);
  const myList = await directus.items('nameofCollection').readMany();

  return myList 
}
```

**But I am getting an error in typescript telling me that expression was expected.
here:**

```
  const directus = DirectusConnection(<DirectusCollection>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a generic parameter:

```js
export function DirectusConnection<T>() {
  return new Directus<T>('https://mysamelink/');
}

// or if you want to use a parameter as that generic type
// but `title` isn't being used anywhere in this function
export function DirectusConnection<T>(title: T) {
  return new Directus<T>('https://mysamelink/');
}

// then later:
const directus = DirectusConnection<CollectionsNameChanges>();
```

[Generics documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Comment: gettting Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'TypeMap'.(type parameter) T in DirectusConnection<T>(): Directus<T>

Comment: try changing it to <T extends TypeMap>.